# Order of evaluation of if statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

So I thought I found a typo in code I was working on. I thought 'not' would operate on string "eta" and make it False and False is not in the List,so nothing should print -  however in both the below case "Eta not found" is printed. I guess this has something to do with order of evaluation that both statements are equal, right?

```
if not "eta" in ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]:
   print ("Eta not found")

if "eta" not in ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]:
   print ("Eta not found")
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: `if (not "eta") in ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]:
   print ("Eta not found")`  :  Run this , This should make it clear for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` has a  [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `not`, so `not x in a` means `not (x in a)`. Keep in mind two things though.

- `not in` is *a new operator* by itself, not just a conjuction of `not` and `in`. Actually, *it couldn't be*: the `not` operator has to be followed by an expression, not by another operator.
- the python interpreter seems to convert `not x in a` to `x not in a`

Comment: thank you that clarifies my doubt, didn't know 'not in' was considered a separate operator.

Comment: @physicist: it *had* to be that way, see edited answer

Answer (score 3):

The result is the same in both cases because slightly different syntax for the same statement should result in equal results, right? And

`if not "eta" in ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]:`

is the same as:

`if not ("eta" in ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]):`

which is equivalent to:

`if ("eta" not in ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]):`